# Add blur effect to image Loading from URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2

[image]

i want to blur image before displaying which is loading from URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made an extension method for UIImageView to achieve this, you only need to call it once:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public extension UIImageView {


    func blurImage() {
        let darkBlur = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.Light)

        let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: darkBlur)
        blurView.frame = self.bounds 
        self.addSubview(blurView)
    } 
}
```

Comment: but my image is loading from URL

Comment: i am not much aware about Extension,can you please write code how can i achieve this ?

Comment: if i use ThirdParty imageView than this Extension will work?

Comment: You can literally put that in any .swift file and it extends UIImageView. So you can call `imageViewVariable.blurImage()` and then any image that is shown in there will be blurred

Answer (score 0):

Suppose  you try to add blur effect to an ImageView , then

Assign downlaoded Image to ImageView

```
imageView.image = .. code for   download image and assign image to imageView.
```

Then add blur effect

```
var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light)) as UIVisualEffectView

visualEffectView.frame = imageView.bounds

imageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)
```